# Why do we experience temperatures below 37 degrees Celsius as 'hot'?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, sensation, temperature

We always prefer to be in 20-25° C, although our core temperature is about 37°? Why is our skin temperature lower than our core temperature?

Comment: related to http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/if-body-temperature-is-37%c2%b0c-98-6%c2%b0f-why-are-most-people-more-comfortable-at-ar?rq=1